# tkplot in igraph within R

Tags: r, igraph

Here is my code with the corresponding output

```
> tkplot(g.2,vertex.label=nodes,
+   canvas.width=700,
+   canvas.height=700)
[1] 6

> ?tkplot
Warning message:
In rm(list = cmd, envir = .tkplot.env) : object 'tkp.6' not found
```

I get this error no matter what command I run after building and viewing my plot.

This may be obvious, but I can't get at the data from the plot.

```
> tkp.6.getcoords
Error: object 'tkp.6.getcoords' not found
```

Any thoughts?  On Windows 2007 Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R is a functional programming language. tkplot is a bit odd (for R users anyway and apparently for you Pythonistas as well) in that it returns numeric handles to its creations. Try this instead:

```
tkplot.getcoords(6)
```

When I run the example on the tkplot page,  I then get this from tkplot.getcoords(1) since it was my first igraph plot:

```
> tkplot.getcoords(1)
           [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 334.49319  33.82983
 [2,] 362.43837 286.10754
 [3,] 410.61862 324.98319
 [4,] 148.00673 370.91116
 [5,] 195.69191  20.00000
 [6,]  29.49197 430.00000
 [7,]  20.00000 155.05409
 [8,] 388.51103  62.61010
 [9,] 430.00000 133.44695
[10,] 312.76239 168.90260
```