# Another Issue with Coordinates in Igraph for R

Tags: r, igraph

I had some help in the past with getting the coordinates of a network graph plotted in tkplot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130059/tkplot-in-igraph-within-r).  Now I am stumped again.

Here is the output from a new session.

```
> g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed=T, vertices=vert)
> summary(g)
Vertices: 436 
Edges: 1856 
Directed: TRUE 
No graph attributes.
Vertex attributes: name.
No edge attributes.
> tkplot(g, vertex.label=vert$label)
Loading required package: tcltk
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
[1] 1
```

but when I try this, I am getting and error:

```
> lay <- tkplot.getcoords(1)
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'tkp.1' not found
```

I am sure this is due to my lack of knowledge on the topic, but what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you maybe run the command multiple times and closed some windows before so that tkp.1 wasn't already opened. best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the last command was run just after calling the `tkplot` function and the Graph plot is still open? The number, given back before by tkplot, is really 1?

As I do not know anything about your datas, I could play just with the demo datasets, but the following syntax should work for you I suppose:

```
lay <- tkplot.getcoords(tkplot(g, vertex.label=vert$label))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id=tkplot(g)
l=tkplot.getcoords(id)
```

Used to work for me, but it's been a while since I used it.